# Implicit Conversion of 'BOOL'(aka 'bool') to 'id' is disallowed by ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I am trying to transform a value of Pending/Completed to a boolean True/False value

Here is the code for that:

```
RKValueTransformer *transformer = [RKBlockValueTransformer valueTransformerWithValidationBlock:^BOOL(__unsafe_unretained Class sourceClass, __unsafe_unretained Class destinationClass) {
        return ([sourceClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSNumber class]]);
    } transformationBlock:^BOOL(NSNumber *inputValue, __autoreleasing id *outputValue, __unsafe_unretained Class outputClass, NSError *__autoreleasing *error) {
        // validate the input
        RKValueTransformerTestInputValueIsKindOfClass(inputValue, [NSNumber class], error);
        if([inputValue isEqualToNumber:@(Completed)]) {
            *outputValue = YES;
        } else if([inputValue isEqualToNumber:@(Pending)]){
            *outputValue = FALSE;
        }
        return YES;
    }];
```

However, I get the error: `Implicit Conversion of 'BOOL'(aka 'bool') to 'id' is disallowed by ARC`

When i try to set the outputValue to be YES...

What's going on here?

It should match this output:

```
{ 
   “IsCompleted”: true (nullable),
   “Desc”: null (“new description” on edit) 
}
```

Comment: BOOL is not a class - you will need to return an NSNumber that wraps your BOOL value

Comment: How would I do that? Sorry i'm new to Objective-C

Comment: I did use google and nothing useful showed up. Let me know if you can actually answer my question

Answer (score 21):

The `transformationBlock` accepts an input object and needs to output a different object, but BOOL is an intrinsic type, not an object type, so you can't set `*output` to a straight boolean value.

You can set it to an `NSNumber` object that wraps the Boolean value -

```
*output=[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
```

Or use the shorthand

```
*output=@YES;
```

Comment: Isn't this just setting the value to 0 or 1?

Comment: Basically, yes.  I don't know the context of your code, but if you want a bool you should probably just use an if statement instead of the transformer.

Comment: This is a rest kit call

Comment: Depending on the value of `Pending` and `Completed` your transformer code probably isn't doing anything

Comment: Its part of the Restkit framework, in order to transform values you need to go through the transformation block

Comment: Yes, but you are transforming an NSNumber into an NSNumber, so you probably don't need to transform this value

Comment: I need a BOOl value, as in the JSON i'm going to be outputting needs to have a true/false value..

Comment: That is what you have, effectively. You can't have a bool because that isn't an object. An object equivalent to a bool is an NSNumber with a value of 0 or 1. You could also transform to the strings "true" and "false" - it really depends on what your JSON needs to look like.

Comment: Check the updated question for the expected JSON output

Comment: That looks to me that you need to transform it to a string